# Swift iOS -How to get keyboard to present itself at the same exact time a SearchController is presented?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller, uikeyboard

Just for context my keyboard successfully appears so that's not the problem.

I have a searchButton as my rightBarButtonItem, when pressed it modally presents a vc that contains a SearchController. When the SearchController is presented the keyboard is also presented but the keyboard appears a second late, there's like a 1 second delay before it shows itself. Basically the vc appears on the scene and then the keyboard appears afterwards, I cannot get the keyboard to appear at the same time the SearchController is presented. I was on YouTube's and Vimeo's iOS apps and when I pressed their search button the keyboard is presented with the SearchController at the same exact time, there isn't a 1 second delay.

**How can I get the keyboard to present itself at the same time the SearchController is presenting itself?**

button to modally present SearchController:

```
@objc func searchButtonTapped() {
    let searchVC = SearchController()
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: searchVC)
    present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil) 
}
```

SearchController:
 I've already tried adding `searchController.isActive = true` and `searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()`  in `DispatcQeue.main` in `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppea`r and it made no difference

```
class SearchController: UIViewController {

var searchController: UISearchController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.delegate = self
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
    searchController.searchBar.returnKeyType = .search
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.black

    definesPresentationContext = true
    navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    searchController.isActive = true
}

// I tried both of these searchContrller delegate methods SEPERATELY but it made no difference, there's still a 1 second delay
func presentSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}

func didPresentSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Are you setting `navigationItem.searchController` to your `UISearchController`? If so, that will take care of all the keyboard hiding & showing for you.

Comment: @NRitH what do you mean and at what point do I set it. The code I have listed above is the same exact code I'm currently using

Answer (score 1):

Sure there is a delay.. ones this animation is completed, then keyboard appears.

```
 present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I didn't ask why there was a delay I asked how to to prevent the delay.

Comment: put this in viewWillAppear
     self.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()

Comment: I already tried that. I did it on the mainqeue and it made no difference. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.
It will immediately open the keyboard if you would not preset view controller with an animation but if we present view controller animation it opens keyboard after the present animation is finished.
Thanks.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Comment: @LanceSamaria Have you also tried without present animation?

Comment: There's still a slight delay but the vc appears to suddenly. It leads to a bad user experience. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @LanceSamaria you can also try like this.

   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
                self.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
        }
    }

If it helps. Thanks

Comment: I tried it in both viewDidAppear and viewWillAppear, it made no difference, Thanks